# Disable external GPS

Tags: usb, gps, android-auto, external-gps

I use Android Auto a lot.
My car's entertainment unit, which I connect my phone to via USB in order to use Android Auto, has it's own GPS antenna.

But it's slow to obtain my location, and often downright wrong, like several kilometers/miles off.
My phone's GPS is a lot faster and gets much better results.

But it seems the external GPS in my car always takes over when I connect to it.

Is there a way to disable it completely, and only rely on the phone's own GPS?

```
Hardware information:
Phone: OnePlus 7 Pro, Android 9, Oxygen OS 9.5.11.GM2BA
Car entertainment unit: Alpine iLX-702D
```

Comment: I would double check the granted permissions and if battery savings mode is enabled (disable any battery savings and test). You may also want to identify which country or region you are using the device if there is some location related issue.

Comment: @MorrisonChang All permissions granted to Android Auto, including location. No indication of battery saving being enabled, couldn't find an app-specific setting for that, just the general one that's disabled. As for the region thing, I don't see what it could be. I mean... either GPS is enabled or it's not, I doubt there's a middle ground. And it does work most of the time, it's just slow (1-2 minutes) at getting a fix on my location at first, and once in a while it's inaccurate. But only in the car, never when the phone is used standalone.